# Can't ping gateway after bridge

Tags: networking, centos

I am running CentOS 6.3 with NetworkManager disabled.

I was trying to set up a network bridge to try out setting up guests w/ kvm. I was creating a bridge before setting up stuff with kvm, just since I wasn't too familiar with it. Something didn't go right and I couldn't ping the gateway ip or anything past it with the bridge in place. The ip, netmask, and gateway are all correct. Before this bridging, the network worked fine.

I created the bridge (ifcfg-br0)

```
DEVICE=br0
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=xx.xx.xx.xx
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GATEWAY=xx.xx.xx.xx
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
STP=on
DELAY=0
```

then I edited the ifcfg-eth0 and removed the ip, netmask, gateway, from there and set it to bridge br0. I restarted network, then used `brctl show` to see that the bridge was made. It showed up in there. This is the point in which I couldn't ping my gateway or anything past.

Since that didn't work, I figured I would just remove the bridge and not mess around with that anymore. I used `brctl delif br0 eth0` and `brctl delbr br0` to remove the bridge. Then I deleted the ifcfg-br0 file and added the ip, netmask, and gateway back into the ifcfg-eth0 file.

Now, I still can't ping the gateway or anything past it from this machine. `route -n` shows the same route that was in place before I started adding a bridge.

Currently, I am accessing the server console through ipmi. Any help with what to look for that could cause this hiccup?

Comment: What is the output of "brctl show"